# Add Trailing Comma to a list, out of the box

Tags: python, scrapy

Let's say I have a list `alist`, how to add a trailing comma out of the box?

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,...,100]
list_wanted = [1,2,3,4,5....,100,]
```

I need a trailing comma for fitting the list into scrapy which only recognizes the last element if there is a trailing comma.

Appreciate help.

Comment: is `alist` a str representation of a list?

Comment: no, both alist and list_wanted are of type `list`, but the list elements would be string

Comment: You should understand that a list has no concept of a "comma" - that's just something people use to separate list elements when displaying them.

Comment: But if you want to add a comma to the end of the last element of the list, you can just do: `alist[-1] += ','`

Comment: I see, but that makes ['1','2','3'] become ['1','2','3,'], not ['1','2','3',] ...

Comment: I don't know how I can explain this better. That's something you can't do - a comma is something associated with a list's representation - not the actual list.

Comment: It's not even something you *can't* do. This is the Stack Overflow equivalent of "You're not right, you're not even wrong." The `,` is put between list elements so you the reader can tell the difference between `[1, 2]` and `[12]`. It's not an actual member of the list and the literals `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,]` both evaluate to the same list.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work unless you change your list to a list of strings because currently they are integers which cannot have a ',' component.

A work around would be to add an arbitrary integer to the end of your list that won't get read in while all of your real  data will.